# Setting <canvas> id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Good morning!

I'm trying to change an icon id that is inside a canvas element.

This looks fine to me, but there must be something I don't quite get since it doesn't work (no icon is shown on the page, just blank space) and the console doesn't return any error. If it helps, "weather" is a string.

```
<canvas id="wIcon" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
----------
$("#wIcon").prop("id",weather);
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: more precisely,

HTML:

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/darkskyapp/skycons/master/skycons.js"></script>
<!--not relevant HTML-->
<canvas id="snow" width="64" height="64"></canvas>
<!--not relevant HTML-->
```

JS:

```
var icons = new Skycons({"color": "orange"});

icons.set("clear-day", Skycons.CLEAR_DAY);
icons.set("clear-night", Skycons.CLEAR_NIGHT);
icons.set("partly-cloudy-day", Skycons.PARTLY_CLOUDY_DAY);
icons.set("partly-cloudy-night", Skycons.PARTLY_CLOUDY_NIGHT);
icons.set("cloudy", Skycons.CLOUDY);
icons.set("rain", Skycons.RAIN);
icons.set("sleet", Skycons.SLEET);
icons.set("snow", Skycons.SNOW);
icons.set("wind", Skycons.WIND);
icons.set("fog", Skycons.FOG);
```

What I wanted to do was changing the [icon](https://darkskyapp.github.io/skycons/) displayed in the document with another one from the set by changing its id. The relevant string was stored in the weather variable, so I thought it was easy to change from one to the other based on what I had in weather with:

```
$("#snow").prop("id",weather);
```

or, as suggested here,

```
$("#snow").attr("id",weather);
```

Sounds like I don't understand this canvas thing enough, so I turned to another solution, that is using [Weather Icons](https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/) which worked out wonderfully using .addClass to the icon (see the [Pen](https://codepen.io/fender90/pen/PjmLqj) if you are curious, and maybe even want to give me a piece of advice about it!), but I'm leaving this question here anyway for future reference if a solution is found.

Comment: id is not a property but an attribute also you have id already for the canvas

Comment: @guradio hum what ? `id` is both an HTML attribute, and an Element property. By modifying the atttribute, you'll also modify the property and by modifying the property, you'll modify the attribute too.

Comment: Your question is really unclear : What do you mean by *"an icon id that is inside a canvas element"* ??? Canvas elements can't have anything visible inside them (actually, IIRC the only allowed content is an `input` tag to allow the keyboard focus). What is this icon you are talking about ? Is this something like an bg-image set via CSS ? If so show us your CSS. Is this some drawing made inside the canvas' context ? If so show us your js.

Comment: So yes, you'll have to tell your js plugin that you did change the id of your canvas, I hope it's not checking every ms to see if it should update. But without looking too much into the plugin, I guess that an simple `icons.set("snow", Skycons.FOG);`, would have changed your snow icon to a fog one. But now, I'm not sure what answer you are waiting for... Maybe best to delete ?

Comment: Well, the question could be "Why didn't the $("#snow").attr("id",weather); work?" :D, oh, on a sidenote: it was changing only on document ready.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method. Also, you are selecting the canvas, not the icon.

You could do something like

```
<canvas id="wCanvas" width="150" height="150">
  <img id="wIcon" src="...">
</canvas>
```

`$("#wIcon").attr("id", weather);`

Comment: @FabioMancin What version of jquery are you using because it works just fine

Comment: 3.2.1/jquery.min.js, not working. The icon changes if I manually set the id for the icon in HTML, but refuses to change when I do it dynamically with jQuery.

Comment: @FabioMancin Check if you have loaded your jquery correct.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="wIcon" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<script>
//$("#wIcon").prop("id","weather");
$("#wIcon").attr("id","weather");
   </script>
```

Try giving attribute instead of prop or give "" within the prop for the id

Comment: No luck. Maybe it matters that the icons are within a set?

Comment: Try this $("#wIcon").prop("id","weather"); . As it was showing "Uncaught ReferenceError: weather is not defined" when it was given  as $("#wIcon").prop("id",weather)